# Java run jar file & include external jar

Tags: java, jar, include, external

Is there a way to pass an external jar file when running a `.jar` application?

I'm trying to run my jar like this:

```
java -jar myJar.jar -cp externalJar.jar
```

The jar file executes fine but I want to look for classes in the external file. I can't include the other classes into my jar, because I want to be able to put any jar file in the same folder as my Jar file and look for classes in there.

The only way to do this right now is by running my app like this:

```
java -cp myJar.jar;externalJar.jar MainClass
```

I do not want to explicitly enter the path to my MainClass to run it's main method.

Answer (score 1):

It really seems that the -cp option is completely ignored when you use the -jar option. At least this is what you can read on the manpage of java about the -jar option:

> Execute a program encapsulated in a JAR file. The first argument is
> the name of a JAR file instead of a startup class name. In order for
> this option to work, the manifest of the JAR file must contain a line
> of the form Main-Class: classname. Here, classname identifies the
> class having the public static void main(String[] args) method that
> serves as your application's starting point. See the Jar tool
> reference page and the Jar trail of the Java Tutorial for information
> about working with Jar files and Jar-file manifests.
>
> When you use this option, **the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user
> class path settings are ignored.**
>
> Note that JAR files that can be run with the "java -jar" option can
> have their execute permissions set so they can be run without using
> "java -jar". Refer to Java Archive (JAR) Files.

I found this in this blogpost here: http://happygiraffe.net/blog/2009/04/30/java-jar-blats-your-classpath/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a specific folder to the classpath during startup and then add your jar file to the folder at later point ?